# Place alias in the dock on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dock

How can I place a alias in the Dock? Drag and drop does not work :(

[image: the problem]

Comment: That's not a programming related question!? Anyway, put it in the right side.

Comment: Nice arrow! It looks like freehand;-)

Answer (score 15):

The main area of the Dock (i.e. the left hand side if the Dock is on the bottom of the screen) is **only for applications**.  Therefore, you cannot put your non-application alias here.  This sounds like what you have been trying to do.

**However**, since OS X 10.5, the right had side of the Dock (again if it is on the bottom of the screen) next to the Trash allows you to put files, folders, and therefore aliases there.  This feature is called **[Stacks](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/dock-and-finder.html)**.  When you first installed OS X you probably had a stack for your `~/Downloads` folder there.  Further files or folders can be added as you the user see fit.

Try dragging your alias file there and you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented.

- I can create an alias to an application and drag it to the dock.
- I cannot drag a file (non-application) to the dock, nor an alias to a file.

I diagnose that 'zmi.ica' is not an application.

Comment: Indeed, this is not an alias from an application, its an alias from an regular file which is linked to an application. If I put the alias file into the right side it works!

Answer (score 0):

A substitute for an alias or symlink in the dock (works on High Sierra 10.13.6).

Example: I wanted to run an old version of iTunes. The OS (or possibly iTunes itself) insists that it be invoked as "iTunes.app". After removing the unwanted version of iTunes (which itself is another procedure):

1. In /Applications/iTunesVersions: iTunes12.6.5.3.app [my directory and old iTunes version]
2. In /Applications, create symlink:
   iTunes.app -> /Applications/iTunesVersions /iTunes12.6.5.3.app
3. The symlink is clickable. Click it and invoke iTunes through the symlink. The iTunes icon will appear on the right-hand side of the dock.
4. Click on the "options-dot" under the iTunes icon in the dock and select Options->Keep In Doc. Quit iTunes.
5. In order to move the iTunes icon to the dock position of your choice, hold down the command and option keys while holding the mouse button [left] or trackpad button and move it to where you want it in the dock.

It's not a symlink or an alias, but it IS a working dock icon and it's where you want it.